# convertir un proceso almacenado en sqlServer a Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql-9.3

Buenas noches tengo por acá unos procesos almacenados en `sqlserver` y me gustaria implementarlos en `postgres`, solo necesito que me epliquen por favor cual es el elemento de salida en postgres y la vairable ya que son muchos y no seria correcto que los coloque todos aqui

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create proc [dbo].[spanular_ingreso]
@idingreso int
as
update ingreso set estado='ANULADO'
where idingreso=@idingreso


GO
CREATE proc [dbo].[spbuscar_ingreso_fecha]
@textobuscar varchar(50),
@textobuscar2 varchar(50)
as
SELECT ingreso.idingreso,
(trabajador.apellidos +' '+ trabajador.nombre) as Trabajador, 
proveedor.razon_social  as proveedor,
ingreso.fecha, ingreso.tipo_comprobante, 
ingreso.serie, ingreso.correlativo,
ingreso.estado, sum(detalle_ingreso.precio_compra*
detalle_ingreso.stock_inicial) as Total,ingreso.igv as Impuesto
FROM detalle_ingreso INNER JOIN ingreso 
ON detalle_ingreso.idingreso = ingreso.idingreso 
INNER JOIN proveedor 
ON ingreso.idproveedor = proveedor.idproveedor 
INNER JOIN dbo.trabajador 
ON ingreso.idtrabajador = trabajador.idtrabajador
group by
ingreso.idingreso,
trabajador.apellidos +' '+ trabajador.nombre, 
proveedor.razon_social,
ingreso.fecha, ingreso.tipo_comprobante, 
ingreso.serie, ingreso.correlativo,
ingreso.estado,ingreso.igv
having ingreso.fecha>=@textobuscar and ingreso.fecha<=@textobuscar2

GO
```

uno sencillo y uno complejo para que me quede bastante claro, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En PostgreSQL, no hay una distinción entre un *stored procedure* y una *función*. Ambos se definen como funciones.

**1. Stored Procedure sencillo**

En este caso, como solo se trata de una sentencia SQL, pero sin necesidad de devolver algún valor, puedes definirlo como una función que devuelve `void` y puedes usar el lenguaje `SQL`:

```
create function spanular_ingreso(paramIdIngreso int)
returns void as $$
  update ingreso set estado='ANULADO'
  where idingreso=paramIdIngreso;
$$ language sql;
```

Aunque no parezca intuitivo, para ejecutar esta función, puedes hacerlo con un `SELECT`:

```
select spanular_ingreso(123);
```

[**Demostración simplificada**](http://rextester.com/XVUX24321).

Si te molesta la conciencia de usar un `SELECT` para ejecutar una función que no devuelve nada, puedes ejecutarlo usando la palabra clave [`PERFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) dentro de un bloque anónimo:

```
do $$
  begin
    perform spanular_ingreso(123);
  end
$$;
```

[**Demostración simplificada**](http://rextester.com/WTDB60985).

**2. Stored Procedure complejo**

Aunque dices que este stored procedure es más complejo, en realidad solo se trata de una simple consulta SQL, por lo que, nuevamente, puedes definir una función con el lenguaje SQL. La diferencia esta vez es que la claúsula `RETURNS` no dice `void`, sino `TABLE(...)` con los nombres de las columnas y sus tipos que la función va a devolver. No conozco los tipos de tus tablas, así que puse algo para el ejemplo, pero tendrías que ajustarlo a los tipos correctos. (*Nota: me parece raro que estés usando parámetros de tipo `varchar` para compararlos con un campo que se llama `fecha`. También no tiene sentido que la comparación se haga en el `HAVING` en vez de en un `WHERE`. Pero voy a ignorar esos detalles y otros en este ejemplo*):

```
create function spbuscar_ingreso_fecha(textobuscar varchar(50), textobuscar2 varchar(50))
returns table(
          idingreso int,
          Trabajador varchar(100),
          proveedor varchar(100),
          fecha varchar(50),
          tipo_comprobante varchar(50),
          serie int,
          correlativo int,
          estado varchar(50),
          Total numeric(10,2),
          Impuesto int)
as $$
  SELECT ingreso.idingreso,
  (trabajador.apellidos || ' ' || trabajador.nombre) as Trabajador, 
  proveedor.razon_social  as proveedor,
  ingreso.fecha, ingreso.tipo_comprobante, 
  ingreso.serie, ingreso.correlativo,
  ingreso.estado, sum(detalle_ingreso.precio_compra*
  detalle_ingreso.stock_inicial) as Total,ingreso.igv as Impuesto
  FROM detalle_ingreso INNER JOIN ingreso 
  ON detalle_ingreso.idingreso = ingreso.idingreso 
  INNER JOIN proveedor 
  ON ingreso.idproveedor = proveedor.idproveedor 
  INNER JOIN dbo.trabajador 
  ON ingreso.idtrabajador = trabajador.idtrabajador
  group by
  ingreso.idingreso,
  trabajador.apellidos || ' ' || trabajador.nombre, 
  proveedor.razon_social,
  ingreso.fecha, ingreso.tipo_comprobante, 
  ingreso.serie, ingreso.correlativo,
  ingreso.estado,ingreso.igv
  having ingreso.fecha>=textobuscar and ingreso.fecha<=textobuscar2;
$$ language sql;
```

Y para ejecutar esta función, lo harías de esta manera:

```
select * from spbuscar_ingreso_fecha('2010-01-01', '2012-01-01')
```

[**Demostración simplificada**](http://rextester.com/OCA33877).

Comment: muchas gracias, intentare con los demás proceso por la noche haber como me va, porque `sqlserver` me ha dado muchos problemas de conexión

Comment: @sstan, ¿Como llamarias ese store procedure desde C#?

Comment: @Pedro: Lo llamaría igual que una consulta SQL normal, excepto que, en vez del nombre de una tabla en la cláusula `FROM`, allí pones el nombre de la función con parámetros: `select * from funcion('valor1', 'valor2')`. No lo ejecutes como un stored procedure, porque no lo es. De hecho, en PostgreSQL, en realidad no existen los stored procedures, de modo que no hay que pensar en esos términos. Son funciones, que en este caso, hasta se pueden considerar como vistas parametrizadas.

Comment: @sstan me da error la función que cree hace un rato lo probé en su administrador de consultas y me manda varios errores publique una nueva pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43626/como-crear-un-store-procedure-en-posgresql si es una funcion entonces construyamos la funcion como tal, sin ponerles tablas

Comment: @sstan, Estas seguro que va $$ language sql;