# Crear Store Procedure en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Deseo crear un store procedure en PostgreSQL pero veo que siempre lleva un return, lo que yo necesito es hacer un simple LIKE no necesito que me retorne nada, este es mi query tiene errores de sintaxis por ejemplo le falta un AS después del nombre del store, ¿a los parámetros le puedo poner un @idarticulo?

```
CREATE FUNCTION uspSelectlist(varchar, varchar) 
idarticulo varchar(6);
 descripcion varchar(40);
BEGIN
 SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                    WHERE (@idarticulo IS NULL OR idarticulo ILIKE @idarticulo)
                    AND (@descripcion IS NULL OR descripcion ILIKE @descripcion)
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

necesito construir ese store.

Comment: Probaste con hacer que te retorne void? `RETURNS void`

Comment: @PabloClaus, ahora si paso a la siguiente linea pero me da error como se declaran los parámetros en postgresql?, esta bien como estoy decarando en el nombre de del store?

Comment: Ahí publiqué una respuesta. Fijate si te sirve.

Comment: Hola Pedro. Cuando dices que no quieres que retorned nada, me imagino que no es 100% cierto. Sí quieres que te retorne el resultado de la consulta, ¿no? Tal vez estás pensando en términos de SQL Server, donde una consulta en un stored procedure automáticamente te devuelve los resultados como si fuera un `select`...

Comment: Posible duplicado de [convertir un proceso almacenado en sqlServer a Postgresql](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38576/convertir-un-proceso-almacenado-en-sqlserver-a-postgresql). Ve si la 2da parte de mi respuesta en esa otra pregunta no es exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: @sstan este es el mismo ejemplo que me ayudaste hace unos días, la diferencia es que lo estoy metiendo a un store, cuando lo he hecho en sql no he puesto nunca que me retorne algo como un int o algo parecido

Comment: @Pedro: SQL Server != PostgreSQL. Para hacer lo que quieres, vas a tener que decirle que te retorne algo. Marqué tu pregunta como un posible duplicado. Creo que la respuesta allí tiene exactamente lo que buscas. Prueba a ver.

Comment: @sstan, efectivamente me ayudo a resolverlo me faltaba un ; al final del query

Comment: @sstan, ¿Necesito un cursor para que me devuelva las coincidencias del ILIKE? no existe la función uspselectlist(idarticulo := character varying, descripcion := character varying)

Comment: No. no se necesita cursor. ¿Pudistes entender la forma como hice la función en mi otra respuesta? La que simplemente necesita que la ejecutes de esta manera: `select * from spbuscar_ingreso_fecha('2010-01-01', '2012-01-01')`? Los puntos claves: 1) puedes usar el lenguaje SQL, en vez de plpgsql 2) la función debe devolver un table 3) El contenido de la función es simplemente la consulta SQL, no hay cursores ni nada complicado. El ejemplo allí es casi idéntico al tuyo.

Comment: @sstan Como puedo enviarle estos parámetros al postgresql cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usp_selectlist( '" || filter || "' , '" || filter || "')"; voy ha retornar una tabla entonces

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51640/discussion-between-sstan-and-pedro-avila).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En postgre tanto las funciones como los stored procedures se declaran como funciones, con la salvedad de que estos últimos devuelven `void`

Algo asi:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_city(city VARCHAR(70), state CHAR(2)) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cities VALUES (city, state);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

En tu caso:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uspSelectlist(idarticulo varchar(70), descripcion varchar(70)) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                WHERE (idarticulo  IS NULL OR idarticulo LIKE idarticulo)
                AND (descripcion  IS NULL OR descripcion LIKE descripcion);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: A que se deben las dos $$ por que son dos parámetros?

Comment: Me da error en END;